# Command to Search for Filenames Exceeding 143 Characters?

Tags: command-line, filenames, synology

So some background first: I am attempting to convert a non-encrypted shared folder into an encrypted one on my Synology NAS and am seeing this error:

[image: Synology NAS Error]

So I would like to locate the offending files so that I may rename them. I have come up with the following `grep` command: `grep -rle '[^\ ]\{143,\}' *` but it outputs all files with paths greater than 143 characters:

```
#recycle/Music/TO SORT/music/H/Hooligans----Heroes of Hifi/Metalcore Promotions - Heroes of Hifi - 03 Sly Like a Megan Fox.mp3
...
```

What I would like is for grep to split on `/` and then perform its search. Any idea on an efficient command to go about this (directory easily contains hundreds of thousands of files)?

Comment: For a collection of CJK \p{} classes, see this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673340

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
find /your/path | grep -E '[^/]{143,}$'
```

Answer (score 12):

Although the GNU [‘findutils-default’ regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#findutils_002ddefault-regular-expression-syntax) doesn't provide a `{n,m}` interval quantifier, you can use a `-regex` test in GNU `find` if you select a different `regextype`, for example:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[^/]{143,}$'
```

or

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[^/]{143,}$'
```

or

```
find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*/[^/]\{143,\}$'
```

etc. There may be other `regextypes` that support `{n,m}` intervals, either with or without escaping.

Compared to piping the results of `find` to a separate `grep` command, this will match across newlines (i.e. the `find` regex flavors differ from their namesakes in that `.` matches the newline character by default).

Answer (score 5):

If you've already got a locate db, it is very fast at this.

```
locate --regex '.*/[^/]{143,}$'
```